# Using Accumulator inside Pyspark UDF

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, accumulator

I want to access accumulator inside pyspark udf :

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType




accum=spark.sparkContext.accumulator(0)



def prob(g,s):
    if g=='M':
        accum.add(1)
        return 1
    else:
        accum.add(2)
        return accum.value 
    
convertUDF = udf(lambda g,s : prob(g,s),IntegerType())
```

**problem i am getting :**

```
  raise Exception("Accumulator.value cannot be accessed inside tasks")
Exception: Accumulator.value cannot be accessed inside tasks
```

Please let me know how to access accumulator value and how can we change it inside
Pyspark UDF .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cannot** access the `.value` of the accumulator in the udf. From the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.Accumulator.html) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34167615/19261326) too):

> Worker tasks on a Spark cluster can add values to an Accumulator with the += operator, but only the driver program is allowed to access its value, using value.

It is unclear why you need to return `accum.value` in this case. I believe you  only need to return `2` in the `else` block looking at your `if` block:

```py
def prob(g,s):
    if g=='M':
        accum.add(1)
        return 1
    else:
        accum.add(2)
        return 2
```