# Why does worker node not see updates to accumulator on another worker nodes?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm using a `LongAccumulator` as a shared counter in map operations. But it seems that I'm not using it correctly because the state of the counter on the worker nodes is not updated. Here's what my counter class looks like:

```
public class Counter implements Serializable {

   private LongAccumulator counter;

   public Long increment() {
      log.info("Incrementing counter with id: " + counter.id() + " on thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
      counter.add(1);
      Long value = counter.value();
      log.info("Counter's value with id: " + counter.id() + " is: " + value + " on thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
      return value;
   }

   public Counter(JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext) {
      counter = javaSparkContext.sc().longAccumulator();
   }
}
```

As far as I can understand the documentation this should work fine when the application is run within multiple worker nodes:

> Accumulators are variables that are only “added” to through an associative and commutative operation and can therefore be efficiently supported in parallel. They can be used to implement counters (as in MapReduce) or sums. Spark natively supports accumulators of numeric types, and programmers can add support for new types.

But here is the result when the counter is incremented on 2 different workers and as it looks like the state is not shared between the nodes:

> INFO Counter: Incrementing counter with id: 866 on thread: Executor task launch worker-6
>   INFO Counter: Counter's value with id: 866 is: 1 on thread: Executor task launch worker-6
>   INFO Counter: Incrementing counter with id: 866 on thread: Executor task launch worker-0
>   INFO Counter: Counter's value with id: 866 is: 1 on thread: Executor task launch worker-0

Do I understand the accumulators conception wrong or is there any setting that I must start the task with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It [shouldn't work](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators):

> Tasks running on a cluster can then add to it using the add method. However, they cannot read its value. Only the driver program can read the accumulator’s value, using its value method.

Each task has its own accumulator, which is updated locally, and merged with "shared" copy on the driver, once task has finished and result has been reported.

The old `Accumulator` API (now wrapping `AccumulatorV2`) actually thrown an exception when using `value` from within a task, but for some reason it has been omitted in `AccumulatorV2`.

What you experience is actually similar to the old behavior described here [How to print accumulator variable from within task (seem to "work" without calling value method)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31497153/6910411)

Answer (score 0):

From [the answer from @user6910411](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43779855/1305344) (emphasis mine):

> Each task has its own accumulator, which is updated locally, and **merged withing "shared" copy on the driver, once task has finished and result has been reported**.

That part of the answer in bold is not 100% correct.

The current values of the internal and external accumulators are sent to the driver every executor heartbeat that has to happen at regular intervals or the driver assumes an executor's lost.

The regular interval is controlled by [spark.executor.heartbeatInterval](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#execution-behavior) property which is `10s` by default.

> Interval between each executor's heartbeats to the driver. Heartbeats let the driver know that the executor is still alive and update it with metrics for in-progress tasks. `spark.executor.heartbeatInterval` should be significantly less than `spark.network.timeout`.

As quoted above, the heartbeat is the "transport layer" to pass the partial updates to accumulators (on executors) to the driver.

There are two kinds of accumulators -- internal and non-internal (for the lack of more proper name I'm going to call the non-internal accumulators non-internal).

The internal accumulators are used for task metrics that Spark uses to let an administrator/operator know what happens under the covers.

The same mechanism Spark uses to send partial updates to non-internal accumulators so the local updates to the accumulators (on executors where tasks run) are visible to the driver every executor heartbeat.

I'm not sure about that, but the driver might not give them to the code (= to the outside world), but the main point is to know that the driver knows the current value of an accumulator (delayed by executor heartbeat).

---

BTW, the question is about worker nodes being the boundary of accumulator updates but in reality this is a task alone that creates the visibility boundary for accumulator updates. It does not really matter if you have one or two worker nodes (with one or more executors) as you won't see the accumulator updates across tasks on a single executor too.

Accumulator updates are local to a task and it's in the discretion of the driver and a task to be informed about any update to an accumulator.